# How does a tensor from cotangent and tangent spaces transform?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, tensor-calculus

In Sean Carroll's Spacetime and Geometry An Introduction to General Relativity Chapter 2, there is an example of tensor transformation from $x,y$ coordinates to primed ones using $$(x',y') = (\frac{2x}{y},\frac{y}{2}).\tag{1}$$ The given tensor is $$ S_{\mu\nu} = \left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & x^2 \\
\end{matrix}\right)\tag{2}
 $$
Which is a (0,2) tensor on a 2D manifold.

I want to calculate $S_{\mu'\nu'} $ which from what I understand is

$$S_{\mu'\nu'} = \frac{\partial{x^\mu}}{\partial{x^{\mu'}}} \frac{\partial{x^\nu}}{\partial{x^{\nu'}}} S_{\mu\nu} \tag{3}$$ in the given coordinates. (I mean the indices match right?)

Can someone show (refer) a detailed derivation of this? I essentially want to know what the form of the matrices of the transformation are. This will give a lot of clarification to the framework to me (and hopefully others).

Edit I: I have calculated all partials (correctly), the problem I have is in intuition, as to what the exact form of the matrices are, I have tried a LOT of combinations but I just can't get it right.

Edit II(answer): As a clarification of the notation used and the operations I'll post a detailed answer.

Given a tensor $S_{\mu\nu}$ in a 2 dimensional manifold the transformation to $S_{\mu'\nu'}$ follows from the equation above. The equation is perfectly fine when we consider the indices and the elements of each matrix. In matrix form though the equation is a little bit different.

Assume $x^1,x^2 = x,y$ and $x^{1'},x^{2'} = x',y'$

$$S_{\mu'\nu'} = 
\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{\partial{x^1}}{\partial{x^{1'}}} & \frac{\partial{x^2}}{\partial{x^{1'}}}\\
\frac{\partial{x^1}}{\partial{x^{2'}}} & \frac{\partial{x^2}}{\partial{x^{2'}}}\\
\end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & x^2\\
\end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{\partial{x^1}}{\partial{x^{1'}}} & \frac{\partial{x^1}}{\partial{x^{2'}}}\\
\frac{\partial{x^2}}{\partial{x^{1'}}} & \frac{\partial{x^2}}{\partial{x^{2'}}}\\
\end{matrix}\right)
 $$
Where the far right matrix is the transpose of the far left. In this example $x' = \frac{2x}{y}$ and $y' = \frac{y}{2}$ which gives $x = x'y'$ and $y = 2y'$. Substitution of those gives:

$$S_{\mu'\nu'} = 
\left(\begin{matrix}
y' & 0\\
x' & 2\\
\end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & x^2\\
\end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix}
y' & x' \\
0 & 2 \\
\end{matrix}\right)
 $$
Which eventually gives
$$S_{\mu'\nu'} = 
\left(\begin{matrix}
(y')^2 & y'x'\\
x'y' & (x')^2 + 4(x'y')^2\\
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

Comment: Have you computed the partial derivatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $y = 2 y'$ and $x = x' y'$ so

$$
\frac{\partial x^0}{\partial x^{0'}} = y'   \\
\frac{\partial x^0}{\partial x^{1'}} = 0   \\
\mbox{etc.}
$$

With this hint I hope you can find the others.

After that it goes
$$
S_{\mu'\nu'} = \sum_{\mu=0}^1 \sum_{\nu=0}^1 K^{\;\mu}_{\mu'} K^{\;\nu}_{\nu'} S_{\mu\nu}
$$
where 
$$
K^{\;\mu}_{\mu'} = \frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x^{\mu'}}
$$
This can also be seen as the matrix product
$$
S' = K S K^T
$$
(to check your understanding of this point, note which row/column index is being summed over in the standard rules of matrix multiplication). But you don't have to use matrices if you don't want to.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, although I found the expressions for the partials I don't understand the form of the transformation matrices. That's the main point of my question.

Comment: @fielder ok I extended my answer a bit.